# Liferay.Upload Component Usage for Multi-file Upload

Tags: file-upload, liferay, liferay-6, jsp-tags, liferay-aui

Developing a custom portlet to upload multiple files in Liferay 6.2.
Found the Liferay.Upload component while going through Liferay Source Code in the Document Library Portlet at the following location:

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/document_library/upload_multiple_file_entries.jsp

We want to reuse this component, but unable to find any documentation regarding the usage.

1. How do we use the `Liferay.Upload` component? What do each of the inputs mean & do?
2. Can we re-use this `Liferay.Upload` in our custom portlet?
3. Any concrete documentation on the usage of `Liferay.Upload`?
4. Any already implemented portlets available on the web with the Source Code available on the web?

Given below is the extract of the usage of the Liferay Upload component:

```
<aui:script use="liferay-upload">
    new Liferay.Upload(
        {
            boundingBox: '#<portlet:namespace />fileUpload',
            deleteFile: '<liferay-portlet:actionURL doAsUserId="<%= user.getUserId() %>"><portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/edit_file_entry" /><portlet:param name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" value="<%= Constants.DELETE_TEMP %>" /><portlet:param name="folderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(folderId) %>" /></liferay-portlet:actionURL>&ticketKey=<%= ticket.getKey() %><liferay-ui:input-permissions-params modelName="<%= DLFileEntryConstants.getClassName() %>" />',
            fileDescription: '<%= StringUtil.merge(PrefsPropsUtil.getStringArray(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_EXTENSIONS, StringPool.COMMA)) %>',
            maxFileSize: '<%= PrefsPropsUtil.getLong(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_MAX_SIZE) %> B',
            metadataContainer: '#<portlet:namespace />commonFileMetadataContainer',
            metadataExplanationContainer: '#<portlet:namespace />metadataExplanationContainer',
            namespace: '<portlet:namespace />',
            tempFileURL: {
                method: Liferay.Service.bind('/dlapp/get-temp-file-entry-names'),
                params: {
                    groupId: <%= scopeGroupId %>,
                    folderId: <%= folderId %>,
                    tempFolderName: 'com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.action.EditFileEntryAction'
                }
            },
            tempRandomSuffix: '<%= EditFileEntryAction.TEMP_RANDOM_SUFFIX %>',
            uploadFile: '<liferay-portlet:actionURL doAsUserId="<%= user.getUserId() %>"><portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/edit_file_entry" /><portlet:param name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" value="<%= Constants.ADD_TEMP %>" /><portlet:param name="folderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(folderId) %>" /></liferay-portlet:actionURL>&ticketKey=<%= ticket.getKey() %><liferay-ui:input-permissions-params modelName="<%= DLFileEntryConstants.getClassName() %>" />'
        }
    );
</aui:script>
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this component is reused [all over](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=use%3D%22liferay-upload%22&type=Code) in Liferay. I think you could reuse it as well. I've found following [documentation](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/js/liferay/upload.js#L126) of initial parameters. I hope it'll help you progress. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I gave it a shot based on Pawel's links and succeeded in a sort-of POC.

view.jsp

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayWindowState"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringPool"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsKeys"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PrefsPropsUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringUtil"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />

This is the <b>Liferay File Upload</b> portlet in View mode.

<portlet:actionURL name="uploadFile" var="uploadFileURL" >
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/singefileuploadaction/view.jsp" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<portlet:resourceURL var="importPortletURL" id="uploadSubmit">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/singefileuploadaction/view.jsp" />
</portlet:resourceURL>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<aui:form action="<%= importPortletURL %>" cssClass="lfr-export-dialog" method="post" name="fm1">

    <div class="lfr-dynamic-uploader">
        <div class="lfr-upload-container" id="<portlet:namespace />fileUpload">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="<portlet:namespace/>fallback"></div>

        <aui:button-row>
            <aui:button cssClass='hide' name="continueButton" type="submit" value="Continue" />
        </aui:button-row>

    <aui:script use="liferay-upload,aui-base">
        var liferayUpload = new Liferay.Upload({
            allowedFileTypes: '<%= StringUtil.merge(PrefsPropsUtil.getStringArray(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_EXTENSIONS, StringPool.COMMA)) %>',
            container: '#<portlet:namespace />fileUpload',
            maxFileSize: <%=Long.parseLong(PrefsPropsUtil.getString(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_MAX_SIZE)) %> / 1024,
            namespace:'<portlet:namespace />',
            uploadFile: '<%=uploadFileURL.toString()%>',        
            tempFileRemoved: function(){console.log('Temp File Removed');},
            'strings.dropFilesText': 'Drop Files Here to Upload.',
            'strings.dropFileText': 'Drop File Here to Upload.',
            'strings.selectFileText': 'Select File to Upload.',
            'strings.selectFilesText': 'Select Files to Upload.',
            'strings.fileCannotBeSavedText': 'File cannot be saved.',
            'strings.pendingFileText': 'This file was previously uploaded but not actually saved',
            'strings.uploadsCompleteText': 'Upload is complete. Please save.',
            multipleFiles: false

        });

        <!-- ASHOK: !IMPORTANT-DO NOT REMOVE-This code is to re-position the Upload Component HTML code which is placed on top of the page by default: Might be a BUG?? -->
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('.component.liferayupload').appendTo("#<portlet:namespace />fileUpload");
        });

        var continueButton = A.one('#<portlet:namespace />continueButton');

        function toggleContinueButton() {
            var uploadedFiles = liferayUpload._fileListContent.all('.upload-file.upload-complete');
            if (uploadedFiles.size() == 1) {
                console.log('One file Upload');
                console.log(uploadedFiles);
                continueButton.show();
            }
            else {
                console.log(uploadedFiles);
                continueButton.hide();
            }
        }


        <!-- Ashok: Upload Component Events BEGIN-->
        <!-- Ashok: Fired when File Upload STARTS-->
        liferayUpload._uploader.on(
                'fileuploadstart',
                function(event) {
                    console.log('File Upload Start');               
                }
            );  
        <!-- Ashok: Fired when File Upload is COMPLETE-->
        Liferay.on(
                'uploadcomplete',
                function(event) {
                    console.log('File Upload Complete');
                }
            );
        <!-- Ashok: Fired when All Uploads are COMPLETE-->
        liferayUpload._uploader.on(
                'alluploadscomplete',
                function(event) {
                    console.log('All Uploads Complete');
                    toggleContinueButton();
                }
            );      
        <!-- Ashok: Fired when Temp file is REMOVED-->
        Liferay.on(
                'tempFileRemoved',
                function(event) {
                    console.log('Temp File Removed');
                    toggleContinueButton();
                }
            );      
        <!-- Ashok: Upload Component Events END-->


        $('#<portlet:namespace />continueButton').on(
            'click',
            function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $('#<portlet:namespace />fm1').ajaxSubmit(
                    {
                        success: function(responseData) {
                            <%-- $('#<portlet:namespace />exportImportOptions').html(responseData); --%>
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    </aui:script>


</aui:form>
```

SingeFileUploadAction.java

```
package com.ashok.liferay.upload;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.ResourceRequest;
import javax.portlet.ResourceResponse;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.upload.UploadPortletRequest;
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

/**
 * Portlet implementation class SingeFileUploadAction
 */
public class SingeFileUploadAction extends MVCPortlet {
  public void uploadFile(ActionRequest actionRequest,
          ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
      System.out.println("In SingeFileUploadAction");
      UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest=PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
      File file =uploadRequest.getFile("file");
      String fileName = uploadRequest.getFileName("file");
      System.out.println("FileName:"+fileName);
      //Mike Test
      Map<String, String[]> reqMap = actionRequest.getParameterMap();
      System.out.println("Printing all actionRequest Params");
      for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : reqMap.entrySet())
      {
          System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()));
      }

      System.out.println("----------\nPrinting all uploadRequest Params");
      Map<String, String[]> upReqMap =uploadRequest.getParameterMap();
      for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : upReqMap.entrySet())
      {
          System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()));
      }

      System.out.println(file.getName());

  }
  public void uploadSubmit(ResourceRequest resourceRequest,
      ResourceResponse resourceResponse)  {
    System.out.println("In uploadSubmit");
    UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest=PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(resourceRequest);
//    File file =uploadRequest.getFile("file");
//    System.out.println(file.getName());

  }
}
```

[image: Liferay File Upload]

Comment: Thank you for the code snippets Ashok. I am trying to implement your solution but I am running into a problem. Whenever I click on the "Continue" button...nothing happens. It seems like I am not able to submit the form via Ajax. I want to extend the functionality to upload multiple files into the Document Library, although I am focusing on uploading single files first.

Comment: The code above doesn't upload to DAM. It just prints out the file metadata. Check the logs if it's printing the details. Why are you developing the multi file upload when it already exists in the DAM portlet? Try and reuse it and customize it via hooks. Will save you a lotta time.

Comment: Thanks, I saw how the file details were printed. My requirement is to create a portlet to upload multiple files into a DAM folder, without affecting the functionality of the DAM in the control panel. I haven't found a good way to customize the DAM portlet yet. One of the reasons why I wouldn't like using Liferay's DAM mechanism would be because it uses Flash. But my main problem is the difficulty from my perspective to customize this portlet with hooks. Any help there would be appreciated.

Comment: The jsp of the DAM portlet where Liferay implmements multiple uploading of files is complex: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/document_library/upload_multiple_file_entries.jsp. I was thinking if customizing the action used by Liferay when uploading multiple files is a good option, but I wouldn't be sure of how to do it and if this would affect the Control Panel DAM behavior.

Comment: Try using Application Adapters to customize the hook changes for your particular Site. Also put some if conditions in the JSP so that your changes are only visible in your Page/Site/URL/User/UserGroup/Role. DAM does use flash but only in case any other drag drop option isn't available. Or atleast that's how I think it works. In any case, it would be better to customize it cuz you would have the base portal code that's tried and tested by the Liferay folks.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions Ashok. By the liferay doc of the Upload component: fallbackContainer {string|object}: A selector or DOM element of the container [b]holding a fallback (in case flash is not supported)[/b]... It seems like Flash would be used first, but I am not  sure. I would like to look into Application Adapters thoroughly, but I am  close to the deadline. I found an alternative solution that I am working on: http://itsliferay.blogspot.com/2011/12/multiple-file-upload-without-using-swf.html. It looks like a good alternative.

Comment: Hey @AshokFelix Where file go after uploaded?

Comment: It's uploaded to tomcat temp folder with some random name. We are not persisting the file in this example. You can use the File object to save it anywhere you want.

Comment: FYI you don't need the jquery hack. The problem with the upload component showing at the top is not a bug in the component, but rather a bug in your code. You should be setting boundingBox, not container.

Comment: @deadcyclo Let me give that a shot :)

Answer (score 2):

After trying to customize this component for my needs, I would recommend a different way to implement file uploading in Liferay.

The lack of documentation of the Liferay.Upload Component plus the complexity of the underlaying code of the Liferay File Upload portlet makes it a difficult path to customize the file uploading implemented in Liferay.

My recommendation is the following: create a new custom portlet and use the jQuery library: **jQuery File UPload plugin**. [Visit its website here.](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) It is a well written library with decent documentation, you can adapt it to your needs since it covers a lot of the settings you would expect in a file uploader.

A summary of how the jsp view in your portlet would be:

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />

File Bulk Uploader

<portlet:actionURL var="uploadFileURL" name="uploadFiles"/>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#multipleupload").uploadFile({
      url:"<%= uploadFileURL.toString() %>",
      multiple:true,
      dragDrop:true,
      sequential:true,
      sequentialCount:1
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="multipleupload">Upload</div>
```

As you can see, using this library makes a really simple implementation of the view, providing a file uploader. Implement afterwards your portlet class action like this:

```java
public void uploadFiles(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException, SystemException, PortalException{

  UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);
  Enumeration<?> paramEnum = uploadRequest.getParameterNames();
  File tempFile;
  Map<String, File> fileMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, File>();

  while (paramEnum.hasMoreElements()){
    String parameter = (String) paramEnum.nextElement();
    if (parameter.startsWith("file")){
      tempFile = uploadRequest.getFile(parameter);

      //******************************************
      //do what you need with the file here
      //******************************************
    }
  }
}
```

When debugging paramEnum, it gets a "file" parameter each time a dragged and dropped file is processed for upload. This is the sequential mechanism and so, the uploadFiles action is triggered for each file:

[image: paramEnum debugging]

Comment: Hi I tried your code but in the Java Class I never get a parameter of type file. Any inputs?

Comment: Hello Tina. If you could debug the "paramEnum" variable after dragging and dropping a file, we could perhaps see if files uploaded are named different than "file"...or if the files are uploaded at all. If no files are found in uploadRequest parameters, try adding this in the uploader attributes in the JSP: allowedTypes:"xls,xlsx,csv" (for example) and test if these file extensions get uploaded as "filex" parameters.  My code was implemented for the jQuery File UPload 4.0.2; I am assuming we are both using the same version.

Comment: I added a screenshot with the "paramEnum" debugging, in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation for **multiple upload files using liferay style**(drag and drop or select file quad). This code will upload the files in a temporary liferay folder (DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID), then inside the method METHODJAVANAMEManageForm in ClientPortlet.java you can get them and using as you want. This is the same behaviour of liferay multiple upload files.

view.jsp

```
<portlet:actionURL windowState="maximized" var="NAMEUrl" name="METHODJAVANAMEManageForm">
</portlet:actionURL>

<form action="<c:out value="${NAMEUrl}"/>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <liferay-util:include page="/jsp/multipleAttach.jsp" servletContext="<%=this.getServletContext()%>"/>
    <!--other <input <div <span.....-->
</form>
```

multipleAttach.jsp:

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayWindowState"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringPool"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsKeys"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PrefsPropsUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.service.TicketLocalServiceUtil"%>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntryConstants" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Constants" %>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.TicketConstants"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.User"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.Ticket"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.Folder"%>
<%@page import="com.sun.mail.imap.DefaultFolder"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.util.portlet.PortletProps"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFolderConstants"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/util" prefix="liferay-util"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui"%>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<liferay-theme:defineObjects/>

 <%
Ticket ticket = TicketLocalServiceUtil.addTicket(user.getCompanyId(), User.class.getName(), user.getUserId(), TicketConstants.TYPE_IMPERSONATE, null, null, new ServiceContext());
%>

<!--REEDME instead of<form> of view.jsp you can also use <aui:form action="<c:out value="${NAMEUrl}"/>" cssClass="lfr-export-dialog" method="post" name="fm1">-->

<div class="lfr-dynamic-uploader">
    <div class="lfr-upload-container" id="<portlet:namespace />fileUpload">
    &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
<div id="<portlet:namespace/>fallback"></div>

<aui:script use="liferay-upload,aui-base">
    var liferayUpload = new Liferay.Upload(
        {
            boundingBox: '#<portlet:namespace />fileUpload',
            deleteFile: '<liferay-portlet:actionURL name="METHODJAVANAMEFordeleteFile" doAsUserId="<%= user.getUserId() %>"><portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/edit_file_entry" /><portlet:param name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" value="<%= Constants.DELETE_TEMP %>" /><portlet:param name="folderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID) %>" /></liferay-portlet:actionURL>&ticketKey=<%= ticket.getKey() %><liferay-ui:input-permissions-params modelName="<%= DLFileEntryConstants.getClassName() %>" />',
            fileDescription: '<%= StringUtil.merge(PrefsPropsUtil.getStringArray(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_EXTENSIONS, StringPool.COMMA)) %>',
            maxFileSize: '<%= PrefsPropsUtil.getLong(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_MAX_SIZE) %>',
            metadataContainer: '#<portlet:namespace />commonFileMetadataContainer',
            metadataExplanationContainer: '#<portlet:namespace />metadataExplanationContainer',
            namespace: '<portlet:namespace />',
            tempFileURL: {
                method: Liferay.Service.bind('/dlapp/get-temp-file-entry-names'),
                params: {
                    groupId: <%= scopeGroupId %>,
                    folderId: <%= DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID %>,
                    tempFolderName: 'com.example.portlet.ClientPortlet' <!-- this is equals of _TEMP_FOLDER_NAME_ATTACHMENT of ClientPortlet.java -->
                }
            },
            uploadFile: '<liferay-portlet:actionURL name="METHODJAVANAMEForuploadFile" doAsUserId="<%= user.getUserId() %>"><portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/edit_file_entry" /><portlet:param name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" value="<%= Constants.ADD_TEMP %>" /><portlet:param name="folderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID) %>" /></liferay-portlet:actionURL>&ticketKey=<%= ticket.getKey() %><liferay-ui:input-permissions-params modelName="<%= DLFileEntryConstants.getClassName() %>" />'
        }
    );
</aui:script>
```

ClientPortlet.java

```
private static final String _TEMP_FOLDER_NAME_ATTACHMENT = ClientPortlet.class.getName();

public void METHODJAVANAMEManageForm(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException 
{
    List<FileEntry> tempFileEntrys = new ArrayList<FileEntry>();
    try
    {
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay  =(ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
        //get selected checkbox of file to upload
        String [] selectedFile = uploadRequest.getParameterValues("selectUploadedFileCheckbox");
        if(selectedFile != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < selectedFile.length; ++i)
            {
                FileEntry tmpfile = TempFileUtil.getTempFile(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), themeDisplay.getUserId(), selectedFile[i], _TEMP_FOLDER_NAME_ATTACHMENT);
                if(tmpfile!=null && tmpfile.getTitle()!=null && (!tmpfile.getTitle().equals("")))
                {
                    tempFileEntrys.add(tmpfile);
                    System.out.println("file: " + tmpfile.getTitle());
                }
            }
        }

        /////upload tempFileEntrys where you needed
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        //delete all tmp files uploaded in liferay tmp folder
        for (FileEntry tmp : tempFileEntrys) 
        {
            try 
            {
                TempFileUtil.deleteTempFile(tmp.getFileEntryId());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("mvcPath","/jsp/viewList.jsp");
}

public void METHODJAVANAMEForuploadFile(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception 
{
    //upload file in liferay tmp folder
    UploadPortletRequest uploadPortletRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    long folderId = ParamUtil.getLong(uploadPortletRequest, "folderId");
    String sourceFileName = uploadPortletRequest.getFileName("file");
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try 
    {
        inputStream = uploadPortletRequest.getFileAsStream("file");
        String contentType = uploadPortletRequest.getContentType("file");
        DLAppServiceUtil.addTempFileEntry(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), folderId, sourceFileName,_TEMP_FOLDER_NAME_ATTACHMENT, inputStream, contentType);
        JSONObject jsonObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("name", sourceFileName);
        jsonObject.put("title", sourceFileName);
        writeJSON(actionRequest, actionResponse, jsonObject);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        UploadException uploadException =(UploadException)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.UPLOAD_EXCEPTION);
        if ((uploadException != null) &&uploadException.isExceededSizeLimit()) 
        {
            throw new FileSizeException(uploadException.getCause());
        }
        else 
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    finally 
    {
        StreamUtil.cleanUp(inputStream);
    }
}       

public void METHODJAVANAMEFordeleteFile(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException 
{
    //delete file from liferay tmp folder, before uploaded
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    long folderId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "folderId");
    String fileName = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "fileName");
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
    try 
    {
        DLAppServiceUtil.deleteTempFileEntry(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), folderId, fileName,_TEMP_FOLDER_NAME_ATTACHMENT);
        jsonObject.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        String errorMessage = themeDisplay.translate("an-unexpected-error-occurred-while-deleting-the-file");
        jsonObject.put("deleted", Boolean.FALSE);
        jsonObject.put("errorMessage", errorMessage);
    }
    writeJSON(actionRequest, actionResponse, jsonObject);
}
```

[Click for Result view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22tlw.jpg)

Comment: Will test this out and let you know.